# How to force the search field to be uppercase in ADF: ListOfValues (LOV) component?

Tags: oracle-adf, uppercase, lov

How can I manipulate a search field LOV component to force it to be uppercase? I can do this for a LOV field, but I don't know how I can access the LOV pop-up search field that you get when clicking the search icon.

Please see below for field I need to make uppercase:

[image: Field that needs to be uppercase]

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I don't think you can modify the behavior or look-n-feel of the built-in search and lov components. The only possibility I see is if ADF Skinning lets you run the CSS command "text-transform: uppercase;" on the search field.

Otherwise, I would just create a custom dialog box, then build your LOV the way you want it to behave. I did that for most of my lovs in my apps. All the lov is, is a table with filtering enabled.

Good luck!